# Bosonic SPT phases with time reversal and a $Z_2$ symmetry

Tags: topological-insulators, topological-order, quantum-anomalies, topological-phase

Consider a bosonic system with time reversal symmetry $\mathcal{T}$ and a unitary on-site $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry. Suppose the symmetry is realized in a special way such that $$\mathcal{T}^2= (-1)^B$$ acting on any physical local operator, where $B=0$ if the operator is $\mathbb{Z}_2$ even, and $B=1$ if the operator is $\mathbb{Z}_2$ odd. How many SPT phases are there, in $1+1$ and $3+1$ dimensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$

I'm not entirely sure that this is what you're looking for, but it seems like the total symmetry is a $G=\Z_2\rtimes \Z_2^T$, with antiunitary $\Z_2^T$, so the number of SPT phases is inside [1]
$$ \mathrm{H}^{d+1}(G,U(1)) = \begin{cases} \Z_2^{(d+2)/2} & d = 0 \mod 2 \\ \Z^{(d+1)/2}_{2} & d = 1 \mod 2 \end{cases}$$
So it would be *two SPT phases* in (1+1)D and *four SPT phases* in (3+1)D.

#### References

[1] X. Chen, Z. C. Gu, Z. X. Liu and X. G. Wen, *Symmetry protected topological orders and the group cohomology of their symmetry group*, [Phys. Rev. B **87**, no.15, 155114 (2013)](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.87.155114) [[arXiv:1106.4772](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.4772)].

Comment: thanks! I think you mean $G= Z_2\rtimes Z_2^T$, and the cohomology is in Eq.(J122) of the paper cited above? If so, there are certain typo above, because d/2 is fractional for d=1 mod 4 etc.

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry about the typos. I corrected both now.